# Is there any function to transform my txt file with "missing fields" to a pandas data frame? The data is a chat transcript and textual data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, data-preprocessing

I have a txt file containing the following fields:

`"Timestamp", "Unread", "Visitor ID", 'Visitor Name', 'Visitor Email', 'Visitor Notes', 'I\P','Country Code', 'Country Name','Region',  'City',  'User Agent', 'Platform', 'Browser'`

and a transcript chat

1. The transcript chat doesn't have a name field
2. Each chat is separated by "================================================================================"

Kindly find the below links of the following txt data described above:

Chat example 1:
[image: chat-example 1]

Chat example 2:
[image: chat example 2]

**Desired sample output:**

```
    Timestamp           Unread     Visitor ID              
   2021-06-09T21:57:17Z    false    9910474.13Njv9b08OK6fq2   
   2021-06-09T16:44:47Z    false    9910474.12djoBnMulmz2hU
```

1. I want to transform the fields into columns and their content into rows
2. There's a last field which is the transcript but it's not named, there's only the transcript data
   How can I transform my txt file into a data frame with all the messiness mentioned above?

Comment: There is no such function, but you can create your own.

Comment: Can you please share a sample of your txt file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create a custom parser using **re** module built in python and then separate out the values and keys using capturing groups. And finally use the pattern.findall(...) or someother iter method

Assuming your file looks something like :
**sample.txt**

```
================================================

Timestamp: 2021-06-09T21:57:17Z 
Unread: false 
Visitor ID: 9910474.13Njv9b080K6fq2 
Visitor Name: naya 
...

================================================

Timestamp: 2021-06-09T21:57:17Z 
Unread: false 
Visitor ID: 9910474.13Njv9b080K6fq2 
Visitor Name: naya 
...

================================================
```

Solution :

```
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import re


def format_item(string: str, replace_with: str = "_"):
    string = string.strip()
    return string.replace(" ", replace_with)


def parse_file(filename: str):
    if filename != None:
        with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
            contents = file.read()
            text_pattern = re.compile(r"=\W+(\w.+?)=+?", flags=re.DOTALL)
            dict_pattern = re.compile(r"(?:(\w.+?): (\w.+))")
            textcontent_list = text_pattern.findall(contents)
            if len(textcontent_list) > 0:
                with open("output.csv", "w") as ouput:
                    once = True
                    for text in textcontent_list:
                        matches = dict_pattern.findall(text)
                        # pprint(matches)  # Uncomment for debug

                        items = matches[0], matches[1], matches[2]
                        keys = [format_item(x[0]) for x in items]
                        values = [format_item(x[1]) for x in items]

                        if once == True:
                            headerline = ",".join(keys)
                            ouput.write(f"{headerline}\n")
                            once = False

                        line = ",".join(values)
                        ouput.write(
                            f"{line}\n"
                        )
            else:
                raise Exception("Invalid format :_:")
            # pprint(matches) #Uncomment for see what keys are present
    else:
        raise Exception("Please pass a filename so that parser can parse")


parse_file("sample.txt")
data = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
print(data)
```

> Note : I used bare exceptions ... You can use your custom exceptions in parsing.

A cool thing i used re module so you can do alot of stuff with keys and values :-)

Comment: @Karim Hazime I am really sorry as i didn't explained you much of the regex stuff and literally skipped that part ... Also did this worked for you ??

Comment: Thank you!! I managed to loop over the titles, moreover I still have a problem I can't find a solution for it,
If you kindly check the chat example 1 and chat example 2 which they are under the same file, I wanted to add a new title after "Browser" field which is called "Transcript"  and It will be below under each transcript. 
Is there any tool to do the following or I am obliged to add them manually?

Comment: @Karim Hazime Hey it is easily possible using the python re module and using little bit knowledge of string slicing .... just try tweaking my above code

Comment: @KarimHazime Hey man check this little [replit](https://replit.com/@Sanmeet007/Parser) for solution for the fileds issue . Hope it helps solve the bigger problem at hand. :-)